# Cannot bind store on Ext.grid.PagingToolbar Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs6.5

I'm developing a extjs project using **6.5.3** version and **modern** toolkit but I have a problem trying to implement a dataview with pagingtoolbar, my view has a viewmodel that contains a store with rest proxy, but when I watch the application, the navigator throw the next error:

> [E] Ext.mixin.Bindable.applyBind(): Cannot bind store on
> Ext.grid.PagingToolbar - missing a setStore method.
>
> Uncaught Error: Cannot bind store on Ext.grid.PagingToolbar - missing
> a setStore method.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: this[binding._config.names.set] is not a function

It's my code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.qlist', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    viewModel: 'myViewmodel',
    controller: 'mycontroller',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'dataview',
        cls: 'qcls',
        bind: {
            store: '{allmyquest}'
        },
        itemTpl: questTpl
    }, {
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        bind: {
            store: '{allmyquest}'
        },
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }]
});
```

Is it the correct form to implement pagination in Extjs Modern toolkit v6.5.3?

Comment: As per [Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.grid.PagingToolbar.html) A toolbar used for paging in grids. Do not instantiate this class directly. Use the `Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar` config of the Paging Toolbar grid plugin to configure its options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar.html) provides an example how to do that:

```
items: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
        title: 'DC Personnel',
        store: store,

        plugins: {
            pagingtoolbar: true
        },

        columns: [
            { text: 'First Name', dataIndex: 'fname',  flex: 1 },
            { text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex: 'lname',  flex: 1 },
            { text: 'Talent',     dataIndex: 'talent', flex: 1 }
        ]
    })
]
```

it's a default toolbar of the grid; therefore one just has to enable the plugin with `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have a question, Is it possible to implement an xtemplate in a grid?

Comment: @CarlosRamirez this works by defining a `virtual` store in the `ViewModel` and I guess one can just bind column headers, eventually use a row-template.

Comment: Martin Zeitler, the solution that i could find was the same list-paging implementation example "http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#listpaging-list" were use the dataview in list and the plugin for pagging taking into account that is possible have an itemTpl.

Comment: @CarlosRamirez the `itemTpl` within a `Grid` is the row-template. the paging plugin should not limit any of that, you just have to combine the configurations, as you may require it; which probably is one of the perks, when using a framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's the first thing in the docs:

> A toolbar used for paging in grids. Do not instantiate this class
>   directly. Use the Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar config of the Paging
>   Toolbar grid plugin to configure its options